# magento - add brand pages to sitemap.xml

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, sitemaps

i have a page with all the brands in my store. generated from the attribute "manufacturer".

all brand have their own brand page. like mydomain.com/canon.html

Is it posible to add all these brandpages to the sitemap.xml?

And how do i do that?

I have magento 1.8.1 CE

Comment: have you tried catalog/googlesitemap? and add a new sitemap?

Comment: I already have 3 sitemaps for The 3 different languages. But I want an extra sitemap with The links to The brand pages.

Comment: you mean for all soreview you will not have them all?

Comment: No. The brand pages Are being generated from a attribute. I now have manually made an sitemap for this. But I would line to have it automated